# How to efficiently prune a list based on "is-subset" condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's suppose I am given `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` and I want to prune it using the following condition

- an `item` should be removed from the dictionary if there exists an `itemLarger != item` in the dictionary such that `item.Value.Union(new[] { item.Key })` is a subset of `itemLarger.Value.Union(new[] { itemLarger.Key })`

That is, each item in the dictionary will be represented by a list of numbers obtained by appending the item's key to the item's value and I want to get rid of those items which are represented by a subset of some other item's representation.

Example:

```
var testResult = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
{                
    { 2, new[] { 3, 4 }},
    { 3, new[] { 2, 4 }},
    { 1, new[] { 2, 3, 4 }},
    { 4, new[] { 2, 3 }}
};
```

In this case, the only element left in the list would be `{1, {2, 3, 4}}`

I can't seem to find some elegant way to do it, since

- `GroupBy` does not allow me to specify which element in particular should be used as the key when I have two that should be groupped
- `Distinct` does not allow me to specify, in case two elements are not distinct, which of them should be kept in the list

Of course it is doable in a trivial way. I wonder if there is some nice one.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will be much different from the "trivial" way you meant, but here's a LINQ solution:

```
var sets = testResult
.Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Set = new HashSet<int>(x.Value.Concat(new[] { x.Key })) })
.ToList();
var res = sets.Where(s => sets.Any(x => x.Set.IsSupersetOf(s.Set) && x.Key != s.Key));
var keysToRemove = res.Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: +1: Better than my approach. It creates the HashSets only once and uses the built in method to determine the subset.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I check for each element x in testResult if this element is subset of any other element in testResult. If it isn't, this element pass 'where' filter in linq expression. Two last lines are conversion of result from list representation to dictionary representation.

```
    var listResult = 
        (from x in testResult 
        where (from y in testResult 
               where !x.Value.Except(y.Value).Any() && x.Key != y.Key 
               select y).Count() == 0 
        select x).ToList();

    var dictionaryResult = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    listResult.ForEach(x => dictionaryResult.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
```

Edit:
We could write it even shorter:

```
testResult = testResult.Where(x => 
  (from y in testResult 
   where !x.Value.Except(y.Value).Any() && x.Key != y.Key 
   select y).Count() == 0).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Please format the code in your answer properly so that it isn't necessary to scroll that much.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most effective way but it's short and kind of readable.

```
var test = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
{                
    { 2, new List<int> { 3, 4 }},
    { 3, new List<int> { 2, 4 }},
    { 1, new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 }},
    { 4, new List<int> { 2, 3 }}
};

var res = test.Where(n => !test.Any(m => m.Key!=n.Key && n.Value.Intersect(m.Value).Count()==n.Value.Count) );
```